# Setting up Matcher for String phrase that may include special characters as literals

Tags: java, regex, file, search

Having trouble figuring out how to match a phrase string to a phrase in file stream. The file I'm dealing with contains random words such as:

```
3 little pigs built houses and 1 little pig went to the market
```

etc. for many lines. There might be special characters in the pattern string such as `V++ **A` so I need the `LITERAL` flag so they can be found instead of having a special meaning in regex.

My pattern is `pattern = Pattern.compile(searchString, Pattern.LITERAL);`

Using "`little pig`" as my pattern string and `matcher.find()` I can locate 2 matches: "little pig" and "little pigs". However, I only want it to match "little pig".

What can I do? I thought about using `matcher.lookingAt()` or `matcher.matches()` but I wouldn't know how to set a proper region when I can't rely on the file string phrases I'm matching being on separate lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 4 (final one): Totally forgot needing `\\s|^` at the start

Edit 3: Did a bit of tweaking to take into account that char after searchString could be end of string `search P = Pattern.compile("\\s"+Pattern.quote(searchString)+"(\\s|$)");`

Edit 2: Ok I got it! `searchP = Pattern.compile("\\s"+Pattern.quote(searchString)+"\\s");`

Not sure why I didn't notice that quote method...oh well first time for everything :)

Edit: Well turns out I got ahead of myself - code didn't help at all for special characters as literalP is converted to String in searchP and loses `LITERAL` rule for the user String.

I think I got it! The following converts the user's string to a literal then puts it in new pattern that allows `\\s`. If anyone sees problems with it, though, please let me know.

```
Pattern literalP = Pattern.compile(searchString, Pattern.LITERAL);
Pattern searchP = Pattern.compile("\\s"+literalPattern+"\\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is "little pig" constantly terminated by any other character like space or linefeed? Then you might add this to the pattern.

```
String pattern = "(little pig)[ \\r\\n]+";
```

Comment: does that conflict with Pattern.LITERAL? (allowing user to use "C++" as pattern) ex. pattern = Pattern.compile(searchString, Pattern.LITERAL); if not, good idea!

Answer (score 0):

How about this pattern which will match any line that contains the string `little pig` only once:

```
^.*little pig.*$
```

Which contains:

- `^` start of line
- `.*` zero or more chars
- `$` end of line

Answer (score 0):

```
String poet = "3 little pigs built houses and 1 little pig went to the market";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(little pig)\\B");
Matcher m = p.matcher(poet);
List<String> idx = new ArrayList<String>();
idx.add(m.group());
System.out.println(idx);
```